# Some clear range and interval definitions

Tags: confidence-interval, definition

What is your or an offical (please provide link to citation) definition of range AND interval ***_***?

Or perhaps put in another way: what is the major important difference between the two terms ***_***?

My perception is the following:

> Statistical definition of "range" is between some defined data points
>   - like max and min values (allows you to state that all data is within the range of max and min value)

AND

> Statistical definition of interval is used to put equal distance(s)
>   above and below OR between specific data OR calculated value(s). So example a 95% confidence interval around the mean means that 95% of all observation are expected to occur within this interval. Another example would be a 10 % interval between the min and max which will create 9 equally distanced interval points between the min and max value.

Do you have other definitions AND/OR examples of ranges AND/OR intervals ***_*__*_***?

Comment: It's more of an English language question. These two are quite synonymous. In both definitions you can replace range with interval or vice versa and it still sounds fine.

Comment: I don't feel like it's a English language question, since most disciplines have different perception of what a term means. Take for instance "elastic" - for regular people this means properties like a rubber band, but to a material engineer it means some specific physical properties that a material hold.

Comment: In this particular instance I don't see the difference. If there is no this definition in the books it's not a term but just a language expression.

Comment: What makes a citation 'official'?

Comment: The characterization of "interval" in this question is unusually narrow and omits many other common meanings of "interval" in statistics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a low quality post.  The term range is very well-defined in statistics and does not need another definition.  The OP seems to know that the meaning is the width of the interval between the minimum and maximum values.

Answer (score 1):

Even in my perception "range" includes values (mean) between "maximum" and "minimum". But I often find authors of published manuscripts refer to "range" while I can still find values in the same article that are out of the mentioned "range". 
This is what really confuses me about the real meaning of range. I presume that at times people refer to "CI" as range.

Comment: There may not be any problem even if you see values out of the mentioned "range". For example, we may have some estimators that don't preserve the range of original parameter and will give us some estimations that are out of the range. This does not contradict the definition of range. Also, the "CI" and "Range" are completely two different terms. I doubt many use "CI" as range, even if they do, they are wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Range is the smallest and largest value found in a set of data, it is used in descriptive statistics which involve only the collected data. whereas confidence interval also involve a set of specified intervals which expressed as percentage or probability that will contain the population parameters, it is used in inference statistic.

Comment: Can you expand on this to show what you think it adds to the previous answer and can you correct your explanation of confidence intervals which is often given but is nonetheless false.